# How to replace woocomerce product image in product loop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display another image for each product in product loop page instant of product featured image. So How to replace woocomerce product image in product loop page?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you will require to do is to remove the woocommerce default hook to show `loop_product_thumnail`

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );`

The next thing you will require to do is to add your own action that will show the product image

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'your_custom_function_name', 10 );

function your_custom_function_name(){
// your code to show specific  image 
}
```